# Row suppression based on multiple independent conditions

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

I have a row group that I need to suppress visibility based on multiple independent conditions. One condition is based on if my grouping field equals one value and the other is based on value returned on a summation expression if a separate field contains a unique identifier. So for Example I am grouping my data on a field name Level 03 if level 3 is equal to cash and my index is greater than zero the cash data point should be excluded. But I also want it to look to another field in the my report table and if that field is equal to a particular identifier (test) then I want it to complete a summation test and suppress the filed is the value of the summation is zero or less than zero.

When I right the expression as =iif(Fields!Level3.Value="Cash",True,iif(Fields!Level3.Value.indexof("Receivable")>0,True, False)) the suppression works and the Cash component is excluded.

However, when I add the next condition the row is still visible with although the all conditions are met/true. I was using this expression:

=iif(Fields!Level3.Value="Cash",True,iif(Fields!Level3.Value.indexof("Receivable")>0,True, False)) AND iif(Fields!Identifier_Code.Value="Test",True, iif(sum(Fields!Year_One.Value<=0 and sum(Fields!Year_two.Value<=0, True, False))

I get an error message that says The visibility Hidden expression for the tablix "Assets" has a scope parameter that is not valid for an aggregate funtion. The scope parameter must be set to a string constant that is equal to either the name of a containing group, the name of a containing data region, or the name of a dataset."

Comment: Looks like you are missing closing parentheses after both your sums e.g. `SUM(Fields!Year_One.Value) <=0` so it thinks the `,True` part near the end is a scope parameter, hence the misleading error message.

Comment: Thank you Alan S.  I made the suggested correction and it was accepted without returning an error.  However, all parameters in my expression were true and the summation of the noted fields equaled zero but the row was still not suppressed.  It is visible with 0 value.  Any thoughts on why?

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing example data. Edit your question to show a sample of data, then explain in pseudo-code what the conditions are and then, based on your sample data, show what rows you would expect to be visible and hidden. I think you have probably got the nesting wrong but it's hard to tell without the sample data.